# Pseudo differential operator in pde

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, pseudo-differential-operators

I'm reading a paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.7565.pdf) and I don't quite understand the way the authors used for the pseudo differential operator inside after looking up some notes on pseudo differential operator.
[image]